# How to use Applescript to delete Conversations whose senders contain email addresses from the Messages app

Tags: applescript, message

I want to use applescript to delete conversations from people who sent me messages using email addresses. I want to keep all conversations from mobile numbers, but delete all conversations, in which my correspondent is an email address.

I've tried:

```
tell application "Messages"
    tell every item
        delete (every item whose sender contains ".com")
    end tell
    save
end tell
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All scriptable applications have an AppleScript Dictionary that can be accessed from Script Editor via the Window --> Library menu.  Reading through an application's dictionary can help you obtain the proper terms for generating a script to do your bidding.

The script below will successfully create a list of chat IDs of all chats (conversations) wherein at least one participant is using an email address.  I have not tested the delete section, since I am not interested in deleting anything.  I strongly recommend that you run Time Machine or another backup service **BEFORE** executing that portion of the script, just in case you get unexpected results.

```
set chatsToKill to {}
tell application "Messages"
    set allChats to every chat
    repeat with eachChat in allChats
        set thePeeps to participants of eachChat
        repeat with oneParticipant in thePeeps
            if oneParticipant's handle contains "@" then
                if chatsToKill does not contain eachChat's id then set end of chatsToKill to eachChat's id
            end if
        end repeat
    end repeat
    repeat with deathChat in chatsToKill
        delete item 1 of (get every chat whose id = deathChat)
    end repeat
end tell
```